# Using AWS FSx file share for SQL Server Backup Directory

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-fsx

I'm trying to use an FSx file share as the Backup directory when installing SQL Server Express on my EC2 instance, but the SQL installer fails to use the UNC path to the FSx file share due to a SeSecurityPrivilege problem.

I can access the file share on FSx with full access from the EC2 instance using File Explorer, but do not know how to set the SeSecurityPrivilege as I don't think it is possible to access the File Server for the FSx share as proposed in the error message from the SQL installer below.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

The error is this:
"SQL Server setup account does not have the SeSecurityPrivilege privilege on the specified file server in the path . This privilege is needed in folder security setting action of SQL Server setup program. To grant this privilege, use the Local Security Policy console on this file server to add SQL Server setup account to "Manage auditing and security log" policy. This setting is available in the "User Rights Assignments" section under Local Policies in the Local Security Policy console."

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the account used to install SQL server doesn't have the "SeSecurityPrivilege" permission on the FSX servers which is required to perform the installation.

By default, the FSx Delegated Administrators Group has this permission.

You need to add your user account to that group on your FSx Windows File System along with Full control on the share and full control on the ntfs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you connected to this machine with the windows/machine administrative. you should connect to this machine with the Active directory administrative user and follow the below document.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/simplify-your-microsoft-sql-server-high-availability-deployments-using-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server/